# Google Sheets Macro; Automatic row selection on search (Find in Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Im trying to make the process of coloring a full row with the content I search for using find in sheet (ctrl+f).

I figured out how to automatically fill a row, but I still need to click on the row# to fully highlight it before I can.

How could I add to my code and make it also select the full row?

Code

```
function colorRedSelectedRange() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setBackground('#ff0000');
};
```

Comment: Where is your find in sheet code?

Answer (score 0):

### You can obtain the row corresponding to the active cell with [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)

Sample:

```js
function colorRedSelectedRange() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
 sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground('#ff0000');
};
```